# Call of a function with String parameter direct vs variable

Tags: c++, string, arduino, esp8266

I ran into a problem I am not really understand developing a software on an ESP8266 using the [ESP8266 core for Arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino). Basically my program crashes if I pass a `String` created at calling a function. I have a function with a `String` as parameter:

```
void SimpleFunc(String str)
{
    ...
}
```

I tried out two ways of calling this function with a very long `String`. **First way** is to create a new `String` variable and pass it:

```
String veryLongString = "veeeerryyyy loooong ........."; //Much longer  in reality!!!
SimpleFunc(veryLongString);
```

**Second way** is to pass the `String` directly:

```
SimpleFunc("veeeerryyyy loooong .........");
```

Running the second sketch results in a crash. Here is a part of the stack:

> umm_assimilate_up at ...\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1163
>
> String::~String() at ...\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/WString.cpp line 720
>
> _umm_free at ...\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1287
>
> free at ...\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c line 1733
>
> String::~String() at ...\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/WString.cpp line 720

Where is the difference in calling the function this ways? Why is the first approach working well and the second not?

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call a string by reference

```
  void foo(std::string const &str)
```

No copy of the underlying  characters is made. If you call by value

```
  void food(std::string str)
```

str is copied, which if it is very long is an expensive operation that could run the machine out of memory.